# how to prepare buffer solutions?

Tags: acid-base

The buffer property of buffer solutions is most likely done by the weak acid's reversible dissociation. Can a weak base with reversible dissociation be used to prepare a buffer solution?if then what should be our choice and if not then please explain.
Note: if this has already been answered please give the url

Comment: http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/acidbaseeqia/buffers.html

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29405/why-does-a-weak-acid-and-a-salt-containing-its-conjugate-base-form-an-acidic-buf  http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9183/can-someone-please-explain-buffers-to-me